# ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range

Tags: python, pytorch

`outputs['panoptic_seg']` is the output from a Detectron2 model (COCO-PanopticSegmentation/panoptic_fpn_R_101_3x) and on certain images I get the following error:

`ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range`

This is the code that is causing the error:

```py
v = Visualizer(img[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale=1.2)
    panoptic_seg, segments_info = outputs['panoptic_seg']
    out_panoptic = v.draw_panoptic_seg(panoptic_seg, segments_info) # this
    image = out_panoptic.get_image()[:, :, ::-1]
```

From other stackoverflow questions and github issues I figured that the alpha channels of the `panoptic_seg` values might be going negative. But I'm quite new to python, numpy, tensors and so on and I don't know how to check it and how to normalize the tensors. Any suggestions?

This is what `panoptic_seg` looks like:

```
tensor([[24, 24, 24,  ..., 24, 24, 24],
        [24, 24, 24,  ..., 24, 24, 24],
        [24, 24, 24,  ..., 24, 24, 24],
        ...,
        [23, 23, 23,  ..., 20, 20, 20],
        [23, 23, 23,  ..., 20, 20, 20],
        [23, 23, 23,  ..., 20, 20, 20]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

And to make things worse, it works on my laptop with the same image, but not on a server.

Comment: OS different on the laptop and on the server?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu on server and macos on laptop

Comment: I compared matplotlib versions, they are the same (the error is coming from that lib)